# Chromecast: Streaming limitations

Tags: video-streaming, chromecast

I'm sorry if this question is not suited for stackoverflow but I'm trying to understand how does [videostream for chromecast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/videostream-for-google-ch/cnciopoikihiagdjbjpnocolokfelagl?utm_source=gmail) works. Technically speaking [chromecast is not able to reproduce .avi files](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media) but still, they play if you use the solution mentioned before.

My question is, are videos selected being live transcoded into h264?

Comment: You are correct, this is not the right forum to ask that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

avi is a container format. It is possible (in fact very common) to put h.264 video inside an avi file. If the file is not h.264 (or vpX) it must be transcoded